# Can live boot a linux but cannot live boot windows 10 into my acer laptop

Tags: windows

Recenlty my Ssd with Ubuntu got corrupted and now I am trying to install windows in the hdd.

But no matter what I do I cannot live boot windows with both DVD and usb stick. I have tried flashing windows in USB stick many ways:

- With Ventoy(Ventoy installs successfully in USB stick but during boot it says, no iso files found)
- Tried both uefi and legacy mode in bios.

The windows, I am trying to install is Windows 10 November 2021 Update , 64 bit version.

However I can easily live boot ubuntu with from usb stick.

Answer (score 1):

Some machines only allow UEFI booting and some of those only read Fat32 formatted USB sticks. So it could be that both is given for you and that your stick is not Fat32 formatted. However, in order to use Win10 latest setup, you need to place a file on the stick (the windows image file (.wim)), that's larger than 4 GB, which will not fit on Fat32! That's a dilemma. Solution:
http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/downloads/ Settings:
[image]